# How to return to previous page and reload it in the same time

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have 2 pages in my project. the first page contains 3 lists and page number 2 is for updating some items from page 1. I use to return to the first page

```
    javascript:history.go(-1)
```

but unfortunately the first page is shown no updates and when I click f5 the changes appear. I want to return to the previous page and reload it. I want to return to the previous page and reload it using javascript or something else not creating a method in my controller

PS: I'm new in asp.net and update methods work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you **always** want to go back to the previous page you can use `document.referrer` to get the url of the previous visited page.
This will give you the url for the page you visited previous. Note that you need to have visited a page before, if not it will return null.

So what you want to do is to have a link containing the value grabbed from `document.referrer`. Get the link and set the href attribute to `document.referrer`

```
<a id="abc" href="test">link</a>

var link = document.getElementById("abc");
link.setAttribute("href", document.referrer);
```

This creates a link that takes you to the previous page and reloads it on new.

Comment: can you give me how to implement the document referrer in my code ? is it in my view ? and i visist the first page always before going to the update page . the code work fine when i press f5 the changes appears but i want to reuturn and the changes appears then whitout pressing f5

Comment: Sir i did what you told me . it returns to the previous page but if i update something and i click submit . the link doesn't work anymore

Comment: @OussamaHsini Is the link pointing to the same page or is it null?

Comment: the link is pointing to the same page after clicking the submit button of update but when i didn't click the submit it poiting to the previous page

Comment: @OussamaHsini yeah the page get refreshed when clicking submit, so the current site is also the previous one. Dont know any workaround on that :(

Answer (score 0):

In *javascript*,
You can use,

```
 window.location.href = "XYZ.html";
```

to reload the page.
Hope This Will help.